# Why not raise EInvalidPointer?

Tags: delphi, invalid-pointer

The Delphi [documentation states](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EInvalidPointer) :

> Never raise an **EInvalidPointer** exception directly. **EInvalidPointer** is raised internally by the memory manager.

I'm writing a custom base class as an alternative to `TInterfacedObject`, following the RTL implementation as closely as possible, and see, by example, that `TInterfacedObject` in the RTL implements `BeforeDestruction` as:

```
procedure TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if RefCount <> 0 then
    Error(reInvalidPtr);  
end;
```

Where `Error(reInvalidPtr)` raises `EInvalidPointer` through a variety of unit-scoped methods local to the RTL.

If I'm writing my own class, how should I implement `BeforeDestruction`?  Why not do this? :

```
procedure TMyInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if RefCount <> 0 then
    raise EInvalidPointer.CreateRes(@SInvalidPointer) at ReturnAddress;
end;
```

Is there something special with the global `InvalidPointer` exception object declared in `SysUtils`?  If this *is* a bad idea, would it be sensible to simply raise a custom exception here?

Comment: I think `System.Error(reInvalidPtr);` is perfectly respectable here. Why not simply do that. So far as I can tell, that is the correct way to signal an invalid pointer exception. If it's good enough for the RTL why shouldn't you do the exact same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be honest, I didn't even try it.  There is no forward declaration of `Error` (it's buried in `implementation`) so I assumed it just wouldn't compile.  Silly me.

Comment: Agreed, absolutely.  I was initially fooled by the `ERROR` const in the `Windows` unit hiding this so I assumed it was just inaccessible - not finding a forward declaration just seemed to confirm it.  Should have just tried it anyways, I guess!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementary to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41249225/243614); what's special about `InvalidPointer`, which is used to raise an `EInvalidPointer`, together with `OutOfMemory` <-> `EOutOfMemory` is explained in more detail in the documentation topic for their ascendant [`EHeapException`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EHeapException):

> **EHeapException** is the exception class for errors related to heap-allocated memory.
>
> **EHeapException**'s descendants—EOutOfMemory and EInvalidPointer—are used
>   to handle failed allocations of dynamic memory and invalid pointer
>   operations.
>
> **Note**: Memory for these exceptions is pre-allocated whenever an application starts and remains allocated as long as the application is
>   running. Never raise **EHeapException** or its descendants directly.

Which amounts to I guess is, it may not be safe to allocate memory for creating these errors once you have problems with memory: for lack of it or possible corruption...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6):

Sidestepping the original question, you can avoid asking it simply by using the same code as the runtime:

```
System.Error(reInvalidPtr);
```