# Where does exception message comes from?

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2007

When exceptions like `EZeroDivide`, `EOverflow`, `EMathError`... are raised, they appear with a default message.

For example, the following code raises an `EZeroDivide` with the following message:

> Floating point division by zero

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  N : Extended;
  D : Extended;
begin
  N := 100;
  D := 0;
  Caption := FloatToStr(N/D);
end;
```

[image: EZeroDivide Floating point division by zero]

When I "manually" raise an `EZeroDivide` exception by code, I have to pass the `Msg` parameter to the constructor and it is raised as an `EZeroDivide` exception which have an empty string message:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  raise EZeroDivide.Create('');
end;
```

[image: EZeroDivide without message]

Where does default exception messages come from?

Comment: The message is defined as resource string SZeroDivide in System.SysConst.pas which is part of the RTL source.

Comment: The message displayed is defined in SysConst.pas as `SZeroDivide`, which the RTL uses when it raises that exception.

Comment: While this question is trivial to answer, we're left wondering why you care?  Merely curiosity, or is there some purpose?  Typically you should never need to create and raise your own `EZeroDivide`.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: Use `system.Error(reZeroDivide)` to raise one. [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Error), [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TRuntimeError).

Comment: @J...: It's for mere curiosity, I was just wondering how Delphi's fathers have chosen to implement exceptions raising. And maybe it could inspire me for implementing something like that

Comment: @Fabrizio If curiosity, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41248963/327083) is loosely related.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those exception instances are generated internally by the RTL.  The specific string in the question can be found in the `resourcestring` section of SysConst.pas

```
 SZeroDivide = 'Floating point division by zero';
```

Internally the RTL uses the `Error` method to raise such exceptions.  The full list of runtime errors is defined in the `System` unit in the following enum :

```
TRuntimeError = (reNone, reOutOfMemory, reInvalidPtr, reDivByZero,
  reRangeError, reIntOverflow, reInvalidOp, reZeroDivide, reOverflow,
  reUnderflow, reInvalidCast, reAccessViolation, rePrivInstruction,
  reControlBreak, reStackOverflow,
  { reVar* used in Variants.pas }
  reVarTypeCast, reVarInvalidOp,
  reVarDispatch, reVarArrayCreate, reVarNotArray, reVarArrayBounds,
  reAssertionFailed,
  reExternalException, { not used here; in SysUtils }
  reIntfCastError, reSafeCallError,
  reMonitorNotLocked, reNoMonitorSupport
{$IF defined(LINUX) or defined(MACOS) or defined(ANDROID)}
  , reQuit
{$ENDIF LINUX or MACOS or ANDROID}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  , reCodesetConversion
{$ENDIF POSIX}
  , rePlatformNotImplemented, reObjectDisposed
  );
```

If you have a genuine reason for raising a runtime error yourself you can do it by calling, for example :

```
 System.Error(reZeroDivide);
```

If you're very observant, you'll notice that `Error` does not have a forward declaration in the `System` unit but exists only in the implementation section.  Typically this would prevent you from having visibility to call the method outside of its containing unit, but the `System` unit is special in many ways and this method is accessible globally.  Just beware that you will also often be including the `Windows` unit and this declares a const named `ERROR` which will usually hide `System.Error`, so scoping it explicitly is usually required.